# Hanging curtain rod from wood coffering on ceiling

Tags: wood, ceiling

I am looking to hang a curtain rod from the ceiling to hang plants from. I would hang from a ceiling joist however there is wood trim/coffered ceiling around the perimeter. The wood is 1” thick.

Can I safely hang the curtain rod from that wood trim or do I need to locate joists behind the trim and screw into those with longer screws? I have attached some pictures for reference.
[image: picture of curtain rod mount plate]

[image: picture of ceiling]

Comment: Any answer will depend on what amount of weight you plan on hanging from the rod.  Give us a good estimate of the weight  you will be placing and a proper answer can be formed.

Comment: Wood trim is usually only attached with thin finishing nails.  The holding power is just enough to hold the trim to the wall/ceiling.  It might hold a very light weight like sheer curtains with very lite rod, but would not chance drapes/large area curtains.  That rod seems heavy enough by itself to pull down the trim.